# Castle Windsor Nhibernate Facility Lazy loading

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, castle-windsor, windsor-nhfacility

I am migrating my mvc web app to use Nhibernate Facility to manage
Nhibernate sessions.

I am encountering this strange problem;

When I register SessionWebModule under web.config/ httpmodules via:

```
<add name="NHibernateSessionWebModule"
type="Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.Components.Web.SessionWebModule,
Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration" />
```

System is unable to lazy load objects. I get no session exception.

If I don't add this to web.config lazy loading is working fine.
Everything part from this seems to be OK as far as regitering Windsor
container and registering Nhibernate Facility goes. Nhibernate
Facility is able to provide session manager and Windsor container is
able to resolve objects.

Ofcourse, without SessionWebModule Nhibernate Facility is near useless
for me as in this situation it is not able to properly manage
sessions. I see datareader is allready open type exceptions which are
no good..

I am stuck and need to urgently get past this problem I will
appreciate any help from you.

I am including below some sections of my configuration and code to
give more information

Web.config:

```
<castle>
        <facilities>
            <facility id="nhibernatefacility" isWeb="false"
type="Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility,
Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration">
                <factory id="nhibernate.factory">
                    <settings>
                        <item
key="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</
item>
                        <item
key="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</item>
                        <item key="connection.connection_string">Data
Source=zzz;Database=xxx;Trusted_Connection=True;</item>
                        <item
key="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</item>
                        <item
key="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory,
NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</item>
                      </settings>
                    <assemblies>
                        <assembly>AppWeb.Domain</assembly>
                    </assemblies>
                </factory>
            </facility>
        </facilities>
    </castle>

<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
              <add name="NHibernateSessionWebModule"
type="Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.Components.Web.SessionWebModule,
Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration" />
        </modules>
</sytem.webServer>
```

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication,
IContainerAccessor
    {
        private static IWindsorContainer container;

        public IWindsorContainer Container
        {
            get { return container; }
        }

        void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Error(Server.GetLastError());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            #region Ignores
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("admin/{*url}");
            #endregion

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Main", id = "" },
                new { controller = @"[^\.]*" }
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            SetupWindsor();
        }

        private void SetupWindsor()
        {
            container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());

            container.Register(
                        AllTypes
                            .FromAssemblyContaining<UserRepository>()
                            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository",
StringComparison.Ordinal))
                            .WithService
                            .FirstInterfaceOnType()
                            .Configure(r =>
r.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest),

AllTypes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                            .BasedOn<IController>()
                            .Configure(c =>
c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest),

                    );
                    //.AddFacility<TransactionFacility>();

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new
WindsorControllerFactory(container));
        }
    }
```

Lazy loading exception:

[LazyInitializationException: Initializing[AppWeb.Domain.City#31135]-
Could not initialize proxy - no Session.]
   NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.Initialize() +138
   NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.GetImplementation() +37
   NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.LazyInitializer.Intercept(InvocationInfo
info) +72
   CityProxy.get_Name() +143
   ASP.views_tour_filters_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w,
Control parameterContainer) in c:\wwwroot\AppWeb\AppWeb.Web\Views\Tour
\Filters.ascx:14
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
ICollection children) +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +59
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+1266

Answer (score 3):

It's by design. You have to keep your session open.

If you are doing web, I suggest you to open the session at the begin of the request and close it at the end.

Get the samples from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx

Comment: Im using "Nhibernate Facility" which is supposed to handle all management of session...

Comment: Maybe, but in your code, you dispose the session explicitly using "Using".

Comment: Nhibernate Facility has a caching mechanism that caches the objects and reuses them in the same context. I updated my question after finding out that my problem was not connected to the using statements. Lazy loading is failing regardless of the using statements as soon as I register the required SessionWebModule

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC, I use an action filter to close my nhibernate sessions

```
public class NHibernateSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public NHibernateSessionAttribute()
    {
        Order = 100;
    }


    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction) return;

         SessionSource.EndContextSession();
    }
}
```

SessionSource is where I'm managing creating my sessions... and the SessionSource.EndContextSession() method essentially calls:

```
    public static void EndContextSession()
    {
        var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(Factory);
        if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                if (session.Transaction != null && session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    // an unhandled exception has occurred and no db commit should be made
                    session.Transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                session.Close();
                session.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have to set the `isWeb`attribute to true:

```
<facility id="nhibernatefacility" isWeb="true" type="Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility, Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration">
```

Comment: why do you add this attribute? what does it change?